# How to get Mouse Pointer location in ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: asp.net

I need to get to show the message if the screen is idle for 30 min.For that i needed Cursor location.If the cursor location is not changed for 30 min then i wanted to change show the message.Please tell me the way to find cursor location.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Any reason you can't use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get the cursor position (or idle time, for that matter) using asp.net. But there is a way to detect the idle time using one of the following plugins:

- [jQuery idle timer](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)
- [YUI idle time detector](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/02/detecting-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript-and-yui-3/)

Answer (score 0):

- [Getting the user idle time with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetIdleTimeWithCS.aspx)
- [Detecting Application
  Idleness](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ApplicationIdle.aspx)

Edit: These only works in WinForms, not with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

C# is not needed/useful here: you can do this check only client-side, which means javascript.

Also, note that 30 minutes is longer than the default session timeout of 20 minutes.

You will need to hook into the onmousemove event to detect movement and (re)set a timer that will display that message in 30 minutes after the latest move.